# np.where doesn't change a numpy array given a list of list

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to conditionally populate a numpy array given a list.

Going through each element of the `my_list` numpy array and look up the `dup_list` to see if it has a pair value e.g., 1 has a pair value of 35. Then, change 1 to 35 in the `my_list`.

```
my_list = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
dup_list = [[1, 35], [4, 31]]
```

Desirable result of the `my_list`:

```
array([35, 2, 3, 31])
```

My code below doesn't change anything...

```
for dup in dup_list:
    np.where(my_list==dup[0], dup[1], my_list) 

my_list

array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Why were you expecting `where` to change things? `where` isn't supposed to change things.

Comment: I was looking at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html and mistakenly thought `where` does make change. Now that I know I need to assign that back to list/numpy array. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying to do:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
dup_list = [[1, 35], [4, 31]]

for dup in dup_list:
    my_list[np.where(my_list==dup[0])] = dup[1]

print(my_list)
```

Result:

```
[35  2  3 31]
```